# Can I send push notifications to a specific device using expo notifications

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

So, I am trying to set up a sort of notification where if you receive a message it can come up as a push notification to the receipient. Maybe storing the receipient's token in the database and using it to send directly to them when a message is sent. I am not quite sure how to set something like this using expo notifications, or any notification library for expo applications.

I can send up general notifications, but not ones directed to specific devices(using the device token or something else?).

Please I need help with this.

Comment: Yes, it's possible- have you tried working through a tutorial? It's better to come here with specific questions about what's not working rather than a whole feature request.